# Take Snapshot of streamed Rtsp video in UWP

Tags: uwp, screenshot, rtsp

I'm trying to acquire a Snapshot of a Rtsp video in an uwp App. To reproduce the video I'm using vlc.MediaElement library (any suggestion of better libraries for this is welcome).
For the time being I'm acquiring a video snapshot with this method:

```
private async void PhotoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Media.Pause();
            RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(Media, ((int)Media.Width / 2), ((int)Media.Height / 2));
            ImgPreview.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
            Media.Play();

        }
```

The result in the ImgPreview element is decent, however when I go to save this to a file with this function:

```
private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StorageLibrary lib = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
                StorageFolder folder = lib.SaveFolder;
                StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("TestPhoto_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

                DisplayInformation display = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
                RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
                await rtb.RenderAsync(ImgPreview);

                IBuffer pixels = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
                DataReader data = DataReader.FromBuffer(pixels);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[pixels.Length];
                data.ReadBytes(bytes);
                using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);


                    encoder.SetPixelData(
                        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                        BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                        (uint)rtb.PixelWidth,
                        (uint)rtb.PixelHeight,
                        display.RawDpiX,
                        display.RawDpiY,
                        bytes);

                    await encoder.FlushAsync();

                    storage.doPut(file.Path, file.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
```

The result is super blurry and for my application I need an higher quality image.
I tried to play around with dpi, but the only result was a totally displaced pixel map with wierd diagonal bands.

Is there a way to solve this issue?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> The result is super blurry and for my application I need an higher quality image.

I checked your code, I found you get `RenderTargetBitmap` of **ImgPreview**, this is no need, you could use MediaElement's RenderTargetBitmap directly that avoid image quality loss.

And you get  half size `RenderTargetBitmap` with the following that will cause low image quality.

```
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(Media, ((int)Media.Width / 2), ((int)Media.Height / 2));
```

Please use full size.

```
 await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(Media, ((int)Media.Width), ((int)Media.Height));

 ......

 private RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap;
 private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         StorageLibrary lib = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
         StorageFolder folder = lib.SaveFolder;
         StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("TestPhoto_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
         DisplayInformation display = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();                 
         IBuffer pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
         DataReader data = DataReader.FromBuffer(pixels);
         byte[] bytes = new byte[pixels.Length];
         data.ReadBytes(bytes);
         using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
         {
             BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);


             encoder.SetPixelData(
                 BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                 BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                 (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                 (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                 display.RawDpiX,
                 display.RawDpiY,
                 bytes);

             await encoder.FlushAsync();

             //storage.doPut(file.Path, file.Name);
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I already tried to render directly MediaElement content, and I tried as well without reducing the size. 
I have however experienced the same issue in any of those cases.

The reason I separated the two things is because I want to save the snapshot not when it's taken, but when the user decides to.
As I told you I also checked if it was related to the double rendering but it is not.

Comment: The quality of snapshot depend on the video source. Have you tried to take a snapshot with capture the video frame do not depend on `RenderTargetBitmap` ?